# Flexible image inside an absolute div

Tags: html, css

How can I make an image scale inside a position absolute div. The image also is an absolute image.

Here's the code:

#### HTML

```html
<div id="home" class="panel">
    <div class="content">
        <p> Welcome! </p>
        <div id="plan" class="home-design">
            <p class="bottom-plan">Learning About the requirements</p>
            <img class="top-plan" src="plan.png" 
                                   style="max-width:100%; height:auto;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
html,body {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    width:100%;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
}

.panel {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
    width:600px;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}

.content {
    width:600px;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    height:100%;
}

.home-design {
    width:225px;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:64px;
    float:left;
}

.home-design p {
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:80px;
    font-size:10px;
}

#plan .top-plan {
    position:absolute;
    left:65px;
    top:30px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#plan img.top-plan:hover {
    opacity:0;
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

The text is behind the image, when the user hover over the image it fades out and goes down. I made the image absolute so that it can go on top of the text.

Here's the image.
[image]

Here's a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/endl3ss/guKS4/1/

**EDIT**

When the window is resize or if the resolution of the monitor is small. the plan image should also resize.

Comment: what's your requirement ?  should image fill the whole div?

Comment: You seem to be using `position: absolute` where it is not really necessary, and this could get in the way of realizing your design.  You want the image (plan.png) to scale, but you did not say with respect to which container, initially (before hover) and after (on hover).

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it well. The main thing is the image plan should decrease in size whenever the window is resized. E.g different resolution.

Comment: The image get's its width relative to which container? `.home-design`, `.content` or `.panel`?  Also, as the window is resized, how do you want `.panel`, `.content` and `.home-design` to behave? right, now, all three have fixed widths.  Obviously, if the window gets bigger, you want the image to get bigger..

Answer (score 0):

It is rather difficult to know exactly what you are after, so depending on what you really want, you could check out the [`scale()` transform-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale):

```
#plan img.top-plan:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guKS4/2/

Alternatively, if you wanted to move it, just animate the `top` value, or `margin-top` or even the [`translateY()` transform-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#translateY).

---

#### EDIT

I realize from your comment, that the sort of scaling you were talking about will not be solved with the `scale()` function. In order to have the content boxes scale to the width of the window, you need to remove the **static widths** (such as `width: 600px` from the containing boxes)

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/guKS4/4 where I removed the widths (and some other irrelevant css). This will allow the `max-width` on the image to take effect and not overflow the viewport.

Comment: I'm sorry this is not the thing I'm after. The thing is when the window is resize the plan image should also resize. That' why I added max-width: 100% to the image.

Comment: @Defyleiti Well, the css is littered with static widths, unless you change to percentages (or remove them) the content is not going to stretch to the window size. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/guKS4/4/ where I removed the widths (and some other irrelevant css)

Comment: @Defyleiti correct. You do have `position: absolute;` on some stuff you really should not (read: content), but it's the **static widths** that prevent them from scaling to the window size.